Disable InteliJ warning "java.util.stream.Gatherer.Integrator is a preview API and may be removed in a future release "
I am trying out new features of Java 22 in IntelliJ. Since Most of my code is using preview features, my editor is full of yellow underscored lines.
The warnings are like:
java.util.stream.Gatherer.Integrator is a preview API and may be removed in a future release 

Is there a way to disable those particular warnings in IntelliJ?

You might be looking for the following configuration to disable it:

Path under Settings for the same would be
Editor > Inspections > Java > Compiler issues > Preview Feature warning

